# Tabularray nested tables aren't vertically aligned

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularray

I wanted to use tables within tables as part of my titlepage design, but it seems the inner tables are always middle-aligned, ignoring the vertical alignment setting for rows of the outer table. How can I fix this?

Minimal example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {|Q[1]|Q[1]|},
    rows={b}
    } 
    \hline
    Anything within this outer table should be bottom-aligned, including the text to the right and the two inner tables below. 
    & Just some bottom-aligned text. \\
    \hline
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {|Q[1]|Q[1]|}}
        \hline
        This is the first of & two inner tables next to each other. \\
        \hline
        This one's longer, meaning & the other table should be bottom-aligned. \\
        \hline
    \end{tblr}
    &
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {|Q[1]|Q[1]|}}
        \hline
        This inner table should be & bottom-aligned \\
        \hline
    \end{tblr}
    \\
    \hline

\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the minimal working example, showing that the inner tables are middle-aligned although they should be bottom-aligned]

Comment: you should set the baseline of the inner tables `\begin{tblr}{colspec = {|Q[1]|Q[1]|},baseline=b}`.